# How do I adjust the dojo BorderContainer layout to handle rotated buttons?

Tags: dojo, transform

I'm trying to implement a navigation toolbar down the left side of my application with rotated buttons. When I rotate the buttons using css transform:rotate, border container still does all of its layout calculations as if the buttons were not rotated so they end up overlapping and in the wrong position vertically. Before I dig into understanding the dijit/layout/utils module well enough to solve this, I'm wondering if anyone already has a solution I'm just not seeing.

Thanks!

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/eric_isakson/2bkKk/6/

JavaScript:

```
require(["dojo/_base/window", "dijit/Toolbar", "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer"], function(win, Toolbar, Button, BorderContainer) {
  var bc = new BorderContainer();
  bc.placeAt(win.body(), "last");
  var tb = new Toolbar({region: "leading"});
  bc.addChild(tb);
  var b1 = new Button({label: "button1"});
  tb.addChild(b1);
  var b2 = new Button({label: "button2"});
  tb.addChild(b2);
  bc.startup();
  tb.startup();
  b1.startup();
  b2.startup();
});
```

CSS

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
overflow:hidden;
}

.dijitBorderContainer {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.dijitButton {
transform:rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
display: block;
}
```

Here is the desired appearance:

[image: vertical buttons rotated 90 degrees CCW]

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, you want your Buttons horizontal?
Then you only need to delete the rows for the rotation.

```
.dijitButton {
display: block;
}
```

Regards, Miriam

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. No, I'm going for vertical buttons rotated 90 degrees CCW. I've clarified the question.